# How do I join an unknown number of rows to another row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this scenario:

Table A:

```
---------------
ID| SOME_VALUE|
---------------
1 | 123223    |
2 | 1232ff    |
---------------
```

Table B:

```
------------------
ID | KEY | VALUE |
------------------
23 | 1   | 435   |
24 | 1   | 436   |
------------------
```

KEY is a reference to to Table A's ID. Can I somehow join these tables so that I get the following result:

Table C

```
-------------------------
ID| SOME_VALUE|    |    |
-------------------------
1 | 123223    |435 |436 |
2 | 1232ff    |    |    |
-------------------------
```

Table C should be able to have any given number of columns depending on how many matching values that are found in Table B.

I hope this enough to explain what I'm after here.

Thanks.

Comment: I personally would change your design. Key value tables are a very difficult design to get to work efficiently and correctly. If you really need keyvalue pairs, then a relational datbase may not be the best place to store them. A noSQL database may be a better choice.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not a great way to solve this problem but I only needed this for a one time thing and it wont be implemented in any application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a Dynamic [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) clause in order to do this.

EDIT:

Ok so I've done some playing around and based on the following sample data:

```
Create Table TableA
(
IDCol int,
SomeValue varchar(50)
)
Create Table TableB
(
IDCol int,
KEYCol int,
Value varchar(50)
)

Insert into TableA
Values (1, '123223')
Insert Into TableA
Values (2,'1232ff')
Insert into TableA
Values (3, '222222')

Insert Into TableB
Values( 23, 1, 435)
Insert Into TableB
Values( 24, 1, 436)

Insert Into TableB
Values( 25, 3, 45)
Insert Into TableB
Values( 26, 3, 46)

Insert Into TableB
Values( 27, 3, 435)
Insert Into TableB
Values( 28, 3, 437)
```

You can execute the following Dynamic SQL.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @pivot_list varchar(max)
declare @pivot_select varchar(max)

Select 
        @pivot_list = Coalesce(@Pivot_List + ', ','') + '[' + Value +']',
        @Pivot_select = Coalesce(@pivot_Select, ', ','') +'IsNull([' + Value +'],'''') as [' + Value + '],'
From 
(
Select distinct Value From dbo.TableB 
)PivotCodes

Set @Sql = '
;With p as (

Select a.IdCol,
        a.SomeValue,
        b.Value
From dbo.TableA a
Left Join dbo.TableB b on a.IdCol = b.KeyCol
)
Select IdCol, SomeValue ' + Left(@pivot_select, Len(@Pivot_Select)-1) + '
From p
Pivot ( Max(Value) for Value in (' + @pivot_list + '
        )
    )as pvt
'

exec (@sql)
```

This gives you the following output:

[image]

Although this works at the moment it would be a nightmare to maintain.  I'd recommend trying to achieve these results somewhere else. i.e not in SQL!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I agree with the "not in SQL" point but this was just for a one time thing.

Answer (score 2):

As [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4441599/446456) has amply illustrated, it's possible to get multiple columns using a dynamic pivot.

I've got a solution that might get you what you need, except that it puts all of the values into a single VARCHAR column. If you can split those results, then you can get what you need.

This method is a trick in SQL Server 2005 that you can use to form a string out of a column of values.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (
   ID INT,
   SomeValue VARCHAR(50)
);
CREATE TABLE #TableB (
   ID INT,
   TableAKEY INT,
   BValue VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES (1, '123223');
INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES (2, '1232ff');
INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES (3, '222222');

INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (23, 1, 435);
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (24, 1, 436);
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (25, 3,  45);
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (26, 3,  46);
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (27, 3, 435);
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (28, 3, 437);

SELECT
   a.ID
   ,a.SomeValue
   ,RTRIM(bvals.BValues) AS ValueList
FROM #TableA AS a
OUTER APPLY (
   -- This has the effect of concatenating all of
   -- the BValues for the given value of a.ID.
   SELECT b.BValue + ' ' AS [text()]
   FROM #TableB AS b
   WHERE a.ID = b.TableAKEY
   ORDER BY b.ID
   FOR XML PATH('')
) AS bvals (BValues)
ORDER BY a.ID
;
```

You'll get this as a result:

```
ID  SomeValue  ValueList
--- ---------- --------------
1   123223     435 436
2   1232ff     NULL
3   222222     45 46 435 437
```

Comment: I actually ended up going with your solution but the accepted answer was closer to my original question. Thanks!

Comment: That's alright. I've built the sort of solution found in the accepted answer, and, like the author says, it's effective but it's a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something a database shouldn't do. Firstly; a table cannot have arbitrary number of columns depending on whatever you'll store. So you will have to put up a maximum number of values anyway. You can get around this by using comma seperated values as value for that cell (or a similar pivot-like solution).

However; if you do have table A and B; i recommend keeping to those two tables; as they seem to be pretty normalised. Should you need a list of b.value given an input a.some_value, the following sql query gives that list.

select b.value from a,b where b.key=a.id a.some_value='INPUT_VALUE';